# Add Hover Effect with Images (wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress, hover, transparency, opacity

What is the best solution for adding Image Transparency - Hover Effect to wordpress? I have a few company logos that I want to be fading until you hover over them....Is there an easy solution? Looking for the right code and css...thanks so much.

Comment: Would you be willing to implement a javascript solution, or are you just looking for pure CSS solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define a class for all your company logo images like this -

```
<img class="company-logo" src="..."/>
```

Then add CSS for company-logo class like this -

```
img.company-logo {
    opacity: 0.5; /* Set this to whatever value you want */
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

img.company-logo:hover {
    opacity: 1; /* make the images fully opaque */
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

Comment: This did not work...going  crazy with this...ugh...Here is my site http://me.lt/3Q3cq - trying to add this to my mountain footer image...let me know?